# Natural deduction question

Tags: solution-verification, natural-deduction

From $(\neg A \land \neg B)$ I will deduce
$\neg(A\lor B)$

1.If $(\neg A \land \neg B)$: 
2.      $\neg A$[and elim]
3.      $\neg B$[and elim]
4.      If A:
            $\neg A$
            $\bot$
5.      If B:
            $\neg B$
            $\bot$

6.      $A \implies \bot$
7.      $B \implies \bot$

8.      $(A \lor B) \implies \bot$[or elim]
9.      $\neg(A \lor B)$

I didnt write all the steps but is the framework of this proof correct?

The perpendicular sign means contradiction; I am pretty sure my proof is a little wrong even though i can’t find my mistake since my teacher said it’s wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is mostly it.

However, to use *disjunction elimination* (OR elim, ${\lor}\mathsf E$), you must have a disjunction to eliminate. So assume one.  After all, when a contradiction is derived from an assumption, you may use *negation introduction* (NOT intro, $\lnot\mathsf I$) to deduce its negation. As is desired.

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~\lnot A\land\lnot B\qquad\mathsf P}{~~2.~\lnot A\qquad\qquad{\land}\mathsf E~1\\~~3.~\lnot B\qquad\qquad{\land}\mathsf E~1\\\fitch{~~4.~A\lor B\qquad\mathsf A}{\fitch{~~5.~A\qquad\mathsf A}{~~6.~\bot\qquad\lnot\mathsf E~5,2}\\\fitch{~~7.~B\qquad\mathsf A}{~~8.~\bot\qquad\lnot\mathsf E~7,3}\\~~9.~\bot\qquad\qquad{\lor}\mathsf E~~4,5{-}6,7{-}8}\\10.~\lnot(A\lor B)\qquad\lnot\mathsf I~4{-}9}$

Comment: In short, you did not need to derive $(A\lor B){\implies}\bot$ but rather show that *on assuming* $A\lor B$ you may derive $\bot$.  A subtle difference.

Comment: Yes this is what I had in mind my phrasing was a bit off (+1)

Comment: Can you please tell me a bit about how to you formatted this?

Comment: I don't see the difference between If A then contradiction and A implies Contradiction isn't it just implies intro ?

Comment: One is a subproof, the other a statement.  Negation Introduction requires the subproof.

Comment: I get that proving A implies Contradiction uses If A then contradiction but doesn't negation intro say that A implies contradiction then we can deduct neg A?

Comment: Yes.  @PaxDaga  When you can derive a contradiction under an assumption, then you *may* use negation introduction.  $$\begin{array}{|l}\quad\begin{array}{|l}~~\mathrm h.~A\qquad\text{Assumption ; the "If A" part}\\\hline ~~\vdots\\~~\mathrm i.~\bot\qquad\text{by some valid derivation (usually involving negation elimination}\end{array}\\~~\mathrm j.~\lnot A\qquad\lnot\mathsf I~\mathrm h{-}\mathrm i\end{array}$$You don't have to, but you may.

Comment: and the top bit is the same as $A\implies \bot$

Comment: No,  $A{\implies}\bot$ is a statement, not a subproof.  You can derive the statement from the subproof (using conditional introduction), or construct the subproof from the statement (using conditional elimination), but these are not identical concepts.

Comment: I mean that the top bit can be replaced by it (Is that correct?)

Comment: Why the downvote?